# How can i resolve "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oT2Z.png)

Error on this line:

```dart
Text( _selectedDate == null ? 'No Date Chosen!': DateFormat.yMd(_selectedDate),),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text(
 _selectedDate == null ? 'No Date Chosen!' : DateFormat.yMd(_selectedDate).toString(),
),
```